# jquery, session, cache

Tags: jquery, session, cookies

I have a problem and I want to resolve it with jQuery.

I have a some Links on the page, and want to get the "text" from the link what was clicked. But I need this text to use on another page. Because when I click this anchor I leave this page , and I go to another one, and I need to use this "Get link text" on the second page.

I Hope it is possible to use browser Cookies with jquery helps ..

Can you help me, if it is possible!!

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    myTarget = $(this).attr('href')+"?txt="+$(this).text();
    window.location.href = myTarget;
});
```

This will pass the text of the link to the next page as a query string parameter called "txt".

Does that help?

Comment: +1 for not abusing cookies. You could also potentially use fragment identifiers (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/intro.html#fragment-uri) to pass the text.

Comment: I agree with this, but having a GET parameter appended to the URL such as `www.example.com?thelinktext=Thisisthetextofthelink` on the requested page would look a bit unwieldy (IMO).

Comment: if you were *really* serious about avoiding the use of cookies here, you could also post the value using a form - but even suggesting that made my soul a little blacker.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the text to request parameters and using it on server side?

Answer (score 0):

[Read here how to set and read cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp) -- then you can make the link set the cookie using `onclick=""` and at the end of the onclick `return true;` to make it link to where it was supposed to right after it finishes. Basically,

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="setCookie('link_title','Go to Google');return true;">
Go to Google
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the cookie plugin for jquery: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.something').click(function() {
        $.cookie('my_cookie', $(this).text());
    });
});


// on your second page
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.something').text($.cookie('my_cookie'));
});
```